# Is Mrs. Figg married?

Tags: harry-potter

Obviously she is, because she's a Mrs, but I see no mentions of her husband in the book (though there's a possibility that I just didn't notice it). What happened to him? Is he dead? He might be, considering Mrs. Figg is an old woman. Also, was he a muggle or a wizard? If he was a wizard, was he an Order member?

Comment: We don't know - nothing has been mentioned about her, really.

Comment: The fact that she's Mrs. Figg, her husband is never mentioned, and she has a lot of cats, suggests she's a widow. I'm not aware of any definitive proof of that fact, though.

Comment: Her husband is never mentioned.  She's called Mrs. Figg, lives alone in a house, and is described as a mad old lady.  Either she's a widow or it's a cover story for her undercover Order work.

Comment: @CHEESE How do we know she lives alone? If we know, I'd say that's enough for an answer of: probably not (any more). Obviously he cold be off working somewhere, but since she's an old woman, her husband would probably be a bit past all that. Not necessarily, obviously, but it's good enough, ain't it?

Comment: When I read your question I thought: Of course she was... Her husband is Mundungus... But this only seems to be an association that my mind made after the Dementor- attack where he was absent and Mrs. Figg was complaining about him...

Comment: Family name : Figg, Given name: Mrs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The very short answer is that we simply don't know.

Mr Figg (if he exists) is never mentioned either by name or even in passing. She certainly appears to live alone but again this isn't explicitly confirmed, nor is her marital status ever discussed, either in the books or the supplementary materials. The [British tradition](https://www.debretts.com/expertise/rites-of-passage/divorce/forms-of-address/) would be to refer to someone as Mrs only if they were married (or possibly separated or widowed) but we simply don't enough about her to answer. For all we know, her honorific is entirely fictional and simply part of her "cover story".

**She appears to live alone.**

> *One day in July, Aunt Petunia took Dudley to London to buy his
>   Smeltings uniform, leaving Harry at Mrs Figg’s. Mrs Figg wasn’t as bad
>   as usual. It turned out she’d broken her leg tripping over one of her
>   cats and she didn’t seem quite as fond of them as before. She let
>   Harry watch television and gave him a bit of chocolate cake that
>   tasted as though she’d had it for several years.*

**When she breaks her leg, there's no mention of anyone taking care of her.**

> *‘Bad news, Vernon,’ she said. ‘Mrs Figg’s broken her leg. She can’t take him.’ She jerked her head in Harry’s direction.
>
>   Dudley’s mouth fell open in horror but Harry’s heart gave a leap. Every year on Dudley’s birthday his parents took him and a friend out for the day, to adventure parks, hamburger bars or the cinema. Every year, Harry was left behind with Mrs Figg, a mad old lady who lived two streets away. Harry hated it there. The whole house smelled of cabbage and Mrs Figg made him look at photographs of all the cats she’d ever owned.*

Beyond that we simply can't answer. She's just the archetypal "mad cat lady" who turns out to have hidden depths.

---

### Speculation time.

Arabella Figg is a squib but she's also a member of the original Order of the Phoenix. She's evidently been willing to put a very large chunk of her life "on hold" to follow Dumbledore's orders and keep Harry safe. Why would anyone be willing to sacrifice more than a decade of their life in this way? If their husband had been a wizard that had been killed by Death-Eaters, of course.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but how do we know that Mrs. Figg was an original OP member?  I've never seen that reference.

Comment: @DougR. Off the top of my head, she's described as 'the old crowd' by dumbledore when he sends sirius out to rally the troops, isn't she?

Comment: @Au101 - I believe you're correct.  I forgot about that.